# Запускается chromedriver, и сразу закрывается с ошибкой

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

когда я открываю браузер через selenium, он сразу закрывается и отправляет код 1, помогите мне пожалуйста решить проблему. Использую pycharm с виртуальным пространством.

```
D:\seleniumparser\main.py:6: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\seleniumparser\chromedriver.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\seleniumparser\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\seleniumparser\chromedriver.exe')
  File "D:\seleniumparser\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "D:\seleniumparser\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "D:\seleniumparser\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "D:\visualcomp\Python39_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\visualcomp\Python39_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 740] Запрошенная операция требует повышения
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\seleniumparser\chromedriver.exe')
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.blast.hk/')
time.sleep(5)
cheats = '//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ol/li[1]/a'
silkacheat = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=cheats)
silkacheat.click()
```

Comment: Попробуйте запускать от имени администатора

Comment: Что иммено? У меня драйвер стоит что бы запускался от имени администратора.

Comment: У вас UAC отключен?

Comment: Да, полностью..

Comment: проблема не в самом пайтоне, а на уровне системы. Может глупо прозвучать, но попробуйте переустановить chromedriver от имени администатора